# Spring Damper System for a Vibrating Motor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, vibrations

Good day people of SE

I have a friend that has a final year project and is stuck.

He has a motor with a small weight at the end of the shaft that causes vibrations.
This motor is on a thin plate.
Beneath the plate, in each corner, is a spring and damper.

He has to formulate a model that describes the power absorbed by the spring damper system.
The aim is to minimize or negate the vibrations to the platform under the spring-damper system.

The weight, spring and damper can be adjusted.

The level of the student is about 3rd year engineering.  The standard of the mechanical engineering department is quite low compared to the other engineering practices, so a purely mathematical solution will be sufficient.  I have no information regarding the position of the weight on the shaft.  I assume it will be a rectangular weight positioned slightly to one side to allow some serious vibrations, but this is a guess.

Where do you suggest we start researching this?

Thank you

EDIT : Thank you Tobias for the comment.  I changed the question as instructed.

Comment: Please, add the restrictions. What are the parameters that can be adjusted (I assume spring and damping constant)? Of what nature should the model be? Purely mathematical model / multibody simulation model? Presumably, the mass is mounted excentric to the shaft? (The first measure would be to center the mass on the shaft if this is a valid solution. But, even with the centered mass the system may still oscillate.) What is the level of knowledge of the student? You should edit the question directly to include these topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to match [mechanical impedance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_impedance) between what the motor produces, and the tuned mass damper.

Read more here http://www.bksv.com/doc/17-179.pdf and here http://arkansas.s.jniosh.go.jp/en/indu_hel/pdf/43-3-3.pdf

[image: PIC]

Comment: Beautiful man.  Thank you.  I will pass this along.  I would upvote your answer, but, I need 15 rep. sorry mate.